# no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'const string' {aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'})

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operator-keyword, getter

I am trying to write a C++ program that has a class `Student`. I am trying to make a getter for the `name` attribute, but I am getting this error:

```
\ApplicationFile.cpp:95:9: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'const string' {aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string'})
  return *name;
```

Any ideas why?

This is what I have done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
    char *AM;
    string name;
    int semester, lessons;
    float *passed;

public:
    Student (const char *am, string n); //Constructor that I give only the serial number (AM) and the name
    Student (const char *am, string n, int semester); //Constructor that I give only the serial number (AM), the name and the semester
    Student (const char *am, string n, int semester, int lessons, float * passed); //Constructor that  I give values to all the attributes
    Student (Student &x);
    void setAm (const char *am); //Set serial number
    char * getAm () const; //Get serial number 
    void setName (string n); //Set name
    string * getName () const; //Get name
};

//Only AM and Name
Student::Student(const char *am, string n)
{
    int l = strlen (am);
    AM = new char [l + 1];
    strcpy (AM, am);

    name = n;
    semester = 1;
    lessons = 0;
    *passed = {0};
}

//Only serial number (am), name (n), semester (e)
Student::Student(const char * am, string n, int e)
{
    int l = strlen (am);
    AM = new char [l + 1];
    strcpy (AM, am);
    name = n;
    semester = e;
    lessons = 0;
    *passed = {0};
}

//Constructor that we give values to all variables
Student::Student(const char * am, string n, int e, int perasm, float *p)
{
    int l = strlen (am), i;
    AM = new char [l + 1];
    strcpy (AM, am);
    name = n;
    semester = e;
    lessons = perasm;

    *passed = *p;
}

void Student::setAm(const char *am)
{
    delete [] AM;
    int l = strlen(am);
    AM = new char[l + 1];
    strcpy (AM, am);
}

char * Student::getAm() const
{
    return AM;
}

void Student::setName (const string s)
{
    name = s;
}

string * Student::getName () const
{
    return *name;
    //return c;
}

int main()
{
    Student Kostas("123", "Kostas");
    cout << Kostas.getAm() <<endl;
    Kostas.setAm("354");
    cout << Kostas.getAm() <<endl;

    float p[] = {5.1, 4.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    Student Giwrgos("678", "Giwrgos", 6, 5, p);
    cout << Giwrgos.getName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is full of pointers - why? A `std::string*` is _usually_ a sign of a mistake being made.

Comment: On a side note, `float *passed;` is never assigned to point at anything, so `*passed = {0};` will have **undefined behavior** at runtime.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the Student class, change

`string * getName () const; //Get name`

to

`string * getName (); //Get name`

and then change:

```
string * Student::getName () const
{
    return *name;
    //return c;
}
```

to:

```
string * Student::getName ()
{
    return &name;
    //return c;
}
```

Comment: Although this solution "works", it is not a good idea to remove the trailing `const` from a getter.  That is a good thing to have.  You should instead fix the issues with the return value, as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As the error states there is no mach for operator `*`, the operand type is `const string`, the operation does not make sense, you are trying to dereference a non-pointer variable and return it as a pointer.

You can return a pointer if you return the address of `name`:

```
const string *Student::getName () const
{
    return &name;    
}
```

You can/should return a reference:

```
const string& Student::getName () const
{
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work I' ll just do it const string getName () const;

Comment: @Costas96, it should work, both options, did you change the declaration? Note that passing by reference is a better option.

Comment: Yes still the same error with *. But with const string& Student::getName () const it's working.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` member is declared as a `string` object, not a `string*` pointer to a `string` object.  Your `getName()` method is declared to return a `string*` pointer, but it is trying to use the `*` operator to turn the `name` object into a pointer, which will not work.  `std::string` does not have such an `operator*` implemented, which is why you are getting the compiler error.  But, more importantly, the `*` operator is simply the wrong operator to use to make a pointer to `name`.  You need to use the `&` address operator instead.

However, since `getName()` is declared as `const`, its implicit `this` pointer is `const`, and thus it accesses the `name` as a `const` object.  You cannot return a *pointer-to-non-const* that points to a `const` object (without using `const_cast`, which you should avoid).

There is no good reason for a non-mutating getter to return a *poiner-to-non-const* that is pointing at internal data.  It should return a *pointer-to-const* instead, eg:

```cpp
const string* Student::getName () const;
// or: string const * Student::getName () const;

...

const string* Student::getName () const
// or: string const * Student::getName () const
{
    return &name;
}
```

And then, you need to dereference that pointer when you are passing the `string` to `std::cout`, eg:

```cpp
cout << *(Giwrgos.getName());
```

However, since the pointer can never be null, it would be better to return the `name` object by *reference-to-const* instead of by *pointer-to-const*:

```cpp
const string& Student::getName () const;
// or: string const & Student::getName () const;

...

const string& Student::getName () const
// or: string const & Student::getName () const
{
    return name;
}

...

cout << Giwrgos.getName();
```

Or, you can return the `name` object by value instead (which will return a *copy* of the `string` data):

```cpp
string Student::getName () const;

...

string Student::getName () const
{
    return name;
}

...

cout << Giwrgos.getName();
```